# RAILS: Calling a parent model within a nested partial form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

Im trying to call a variable from the 'product' model in a 'variant' partial.  I can call an existing variable from the 'variant' using:

```
 <%= f.object.product_id %>
```

But I can't get this to work:

```
<%= f.object.product.id %>
```

I can do this:

```
<%= f.object.product %>
```

But it returns `#<Product:0x007fee2c9a8ec8>` and I don't know what to do with it!

Here's a more detailed overview of the situation:

I have 'store' model that has_many 'products'.  Each 'product' has_many 'variants'. The variants are nested.  Here's the '/store/show.html.erb' file:

```
  <% @store.products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= form_for(product) do |f| %>
          <%= f.fields_for :variants do |builder| %>
            <%= render 'variant_fields', f: builder %>
          <% end %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

And here's the '/store/_variant_fields' partial:

```
<fieldset>
    </table>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td><%= f.label :variant_name %><%= f.text_field :variant_name %></td>         
         </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: what happen when you call `id`? does it return nil?

Comment: When I call 'f.object.product.id ', I get this run time error:  "Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id"

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution would be to pass the product to your partial:

```
<% render 'variant_fields', f: builder, product: f.object %>
```

in your partial:

```
<fieldset>
    </table>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td><%= f.label :variant_name %><%= f.text_field :variant_name %><%= product.inspect %></td>         
          </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
</fieldset>
```

See what product.inspect shows you.

Comment: How would I access that in the partial: 'product.id'?  I stil can't get it to work. It's telling me that it is an "undefined local variable or method `product'.

Comment: I have updated my answer.  I mistakenly thought product was still in scope on the parent form.  I believe `f.object` will still be in scope.  Can you check that out?

Comment: product: f.object didn't work.  I can't seem to get any thing passed to the partial!

Comment: in the partial, you should reference the object as product.  just making sure that's what you're doing.